# How to get the AF_PACKET socket information in Linux

Tags: linux, networking

If one process register an AF_PACKET socket, monitor some link type packets.

How can I get the information about:

1. does any process register AF_PACKET socket?
2. if so, what's the packet type that are being monitored?